# How to update computed property?

Tags: ember.js

I am new to emberjs.
In template, i have
{{labeltext}}

Now, I want 
By default, labeltext should be, 'Hello'
If condition A, then labeltext = Wow
If condition B, then labeltext = Thanks
Is there any way to write the computed property in component in emberjs which will perform above requirements?

Answer (score 0):

In your component,

```
labeltext:Ember.computed('conditionVar',function(){
 var val = this.get('conditionVar');
 if(Ember.isEqual(val,'conditionA')){
  return 'Wow';
 }
 else if(Ember.isEqual(val,'conditionB')) {
  return 'Thanks';
 }
 return 'Hello';
})
```

You might have getter and setter for computed property,

```
labeltext: Ember.computed('conditionVar', function () {
    get(key){
      var val = this.get('conditionVar');
      if (Ember.isEqual(val, 'conditionA')) {
        return 'Wow';
      }else if (Ember.isEqual(val, 'conditionB')) {
        return 'Thanks';
      }
        return 'Hello';
    },
    set(key, value){
      // you can set conditionVar so that it will return the same value when you request it again.
      if(value === 'Wow') {
        this.set('conditionVar', 'conditionA');
      }
      else if(value === 'Thanks') {
        this.set('conditionVar', 'conditionB');
      }
     return value;
    }
    }),
```

Refer official guide: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/object-model/computed-properties/